# Argument 6 passed to Drupal\layout_builder\Plugin\Block\InlineBlock::__construct() must implement interface Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface

Tags: 9, layout-builder

I was upgrading Drupal 8 to 9. I installed 'Upgrade Status' module and fixed as suggested by it. Now it was time to upgrade to D9. I changed on composer.json.

```
"drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^8.9.0",
"drupal/core-recommended": "^8.9.0",
```

To

```
"drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9.1.0",
"drupal/core-recommended": "^9.1.0",
```

Then ran following command:

```
composer update
drush cr
drush updb -y
```

After running the update, I got the Drupal 9.2.6.
When browsing the URL, it showed following error:

> TypeError: Argument 6 passed to
> Drupal\layout_builder\Plugin\Block\InlineBlock::__construct() must
> implement interface Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface, instance of
> Drupal\Core\Logger\LoggerChannel given, called in
> /app/web/core/modules/layout_builder/src/Plugin/Block/InlineBlock.php
> on line 117 in
> Drupal\layout_builder\Plugin\Block\InlineBlock->__construct() (line 95
> of core/modules/layout_builder/src/Plugin/Block/InlineBlock.php).

I googled but could not find out the solution.
Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was a failed patch for:

web/core/modules/layout_builder/src/Plugin/Block/InlineBlock.php

Leading to an InlineBlock.php.rej file being created.

Try the following patch if yours was the same: -

```
diff --git a/core/modules/layout_builder/src/Plugin/Block/InlineBlock.php

diff --git a/web/core/modules/layout_builder/src/Plugin/Block/InlineBlock.php b/web/core/modules/layout_builder/src/Plugin/Block/InlineBlock.php
--- a/core/modules/layout_builder/src/Plugin/Block/InlineBlock.php  (date 1656600871622)
+++ b/core/modules/layout_builder/src/Plugin/Block/InlineBlock.php  (date 1656600871622)
@@ -93,11 +93,13 @@
    * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $current_user
    *   The current user.
    */
-  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager, EntityDisplayRepositoryInterface $entity_display_repository, AccountInterface $current_user) {
+  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager, EntityDisplayRepositoryInterface $entity_display_repository, TimeInterface $time, AccountInterface $current_user = NULL) {
     parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);

     $this->entityTypeManager = $entity_type_manager;
     $this->entityDisplayRepository = $entity_display_repository;
+    $this->time = $time;
+
     $this->currentUser = $current_user;
     if (!empty($this->configuration['block_revision_id']) || !empty($this->configuration['block_serialized'])) {
       $this->isNew = FALSE;
```